# How to calculate ratio of areas of the shaded triangle and the hexagon?

Tags: geometry

How to calculate ratio of areas of the shaded triangle and the hexagon?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Observe that the hexagon is equivalent to 6 equilateral triangles, and the shaded region is equivalent to such a triangle with double height.

Comment: shaded triangle:hexagon == 2*1/6=1/3 =1:3

Comment: Is this the answareshaded triangle:hexagon == 1:3?

Comment: @OMLoo: yes, it is

Comment: May I know the correct way to work out answer for triangle:hexagon ratio in this case?

Comment: $A_{\text{hex}}=6A_{\text{eqtri}}$; $A_{\text{shad}}=2A_{\text{eqtri}}$; $r=A_{\text{shad}}/A_{\text{hex}}=(2A_{\text{eqtri}})/(6A_{\text{eqtri}})=1/3$